# Magnitude of an electric field on a long rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields

> You place $2.7 \: \rm \mu C$ of charge along a long nonconducting rod. The rod extends from $x=0$ farther than you can see along the positive $x$ axis. The charge distribution has the form of a decreasing exponential: $q(x)=q_0e^{-x/\ell}$, where $\ell = 28.6\:\rm mm$. Calculate the electric field magnitude $20\:\rm mm$ from the near end of the rod, along its long axis.

I'm not looking for an actual solution to this problem, I just need help understanding the wording of the question and making sure I know how to begin this problem. Below is my current understanding of the question and approach for tackling this problem.

Consider a two dimensional plane with a rod beginning at the origin and extending very far along the positive x-axis. We want to find the magnitude of the electric field at a point that is $20\:mm$ to the right of the origin, directly on the rod. If we imagine a positively charged test particle at this position, then the left part of the rod exerts a rightward force on the test particle while the right part exerts a leftward force.

The electric force contributed by an infinitesimally small portion of the left rod is given by $$k\frac{dq}{(20-x)^2}$$ where $k$ is Coulomb's constant, $dq$ is infinitesimally small charge, and $(20-x)$ is the disance between the source particle and the test particle. If we solve for $dq$ by taking the first derivative of $q(x)$ and apply this formula to the entire left rod then we obtain $$\frac{-kq_0}{\ell}\int_{0}^{20}\frac{e^{x/\ell}}{(20-x)^2}dx$$

Unfortunately, the inside function lacks an elementary antiderivative. However, it just might be possible to compute the definite integral using some advanced techniques. Right now, I am in the middle of using Feynman's trick to produce a Gaussian integral. (Definitely a bad sign considering this problem is from an intro level physics class) But more importantly, the integral doesn't even exist since $20$ is not an explicit boundary condition. Additionally, even if I shorten the range to make the integral converge, the value will come out to be negative, which I don't think makes sense considering the left rod should exert a rightward (positive) force.

My sources of confusion

1) Have I put the test particle in the wrong place? To me, the question's wording seems to be telling me that the test particle is directly on top of the rod. But I don't think this even makes sense in a physical context since electrical force becomes ridiculously large the closer two positively charged particles are to one another

Perhaps I should just set a boundary condition of $19.999 \: mm$. Or maybe the test particle instead is meant to be placed $20 \: mm$ to the left of the origin.

2) Am I utilizing $q(x)$ in the correct way? It seems natural to just take the first derivative to obtain $dq$, but I can't shake the feeling that $q(x)$ doesn't translate directly to $dq$. $q(0)=q_0$ and the function is constantly decreasing which leads me to believe $q(x)$ represents the amount of charge to the right of $x$. If want to find $dq$, I might to modify $q(x)$ in some way, such as $q_0-q_0e^{-x/\ell}$ for instance.

3) Why would the problem tell me the rod is longer than I can see? Does the rod extend to infinity? Or does the right part of the rod not even matter that much to the electric field at this particular point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not conceptually correct.

1. A small piece of your rod, having length $dx_s$ and centered at $x_s$ will contain a charge $dq= q_0e^{-x_s/\ell}dx_s$.
2. This little piece is at a distance $x_s+20$ from point where you want the field, at $\vec r=-20\hat x$; one end of the rod, located at $x_s=0$ is at a distance $20$ from the point, and this distance increases with $x_s$.
3. You need to integrate *over the source charges*, which are located between $0$ and $\infty$ so your integral will be over $dx_s$ from $0$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the question doesn't quite match the equation it gives you. In continuous charge distribution problems you don't talk about charge at a point but rather linear charge density. Writing $q(x) = q_0e^{-x/\ell}$ means you have some amount charge at a given point. Instead, you should be given something like $\lambda(x) = \lambda_0e^{-x/\ell}$ where $\lambda$ is the linear charge density as a function of position. Then, the charge in a small length $dx$ would be this charge density multiplied by the small length, $dx$. Then $dq=\lambda_0e^{-x/\ell}dx$.

To find what $\lambda_0$ is equal to we use the given total charge of $2.7 \: \rm \mu C$. You integrate $dq$ over the entire length of the rod which is from $0$ to $\infty$ and then set this integral to $2.7 \: \rm \mu C$ then solve for $\lambda_0$.

Now we consider the electric field at the point $20\:\rm mm$ from the end of the rod by integrating 
$$k\frac{dq}{(20+x)^2}$$
along the length of the rod, $0$ to $\infty$.

The denominator of the integral is $20+x$ since $r=20$ when you're at $x=0$ and $r$ increases as you go to larger values of $x$.

Part of the question that can lead to confusion is the statement that $\ell = 28.6\:\rm mm$. $\ell$ is just a parameter in the exponential decay of the linear charge density. If $\ell$ is smaller the charge density decreases faster (shorter distance) and if $\ell$ is larger the charge density decreases slower (longer distance).